# Google Cloud Data Fusion + CI/CD for Data Pipelines

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am just getting started with both, GCP & Google Cloud Data Fusion. Just viewed the intro video. I see that pipelines can be exported. I was wondering how we might promote a pipeline from say, Dev to Prod env? My guess is that after some testing, the exported file is copied to the Prod branch on Git, from where we need to invoke the APIs to deploy it? Also, what about connection details, how do we avoid hard-coding the source/destination configurations & credentials?

Comment: Here's an interesting thread about how to industrialize the deployment > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58839608/import-export-datafusion-pipelines/58922941#58922941

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You would have to export and re-import the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

About the first question, if you have different environments for development and production, you can export your pipeline and import it in the correct environment.
I didn't understand the second question very well. In the official `Data Fusion` plugins there is a standard way to provide your credentials. If you need a better answer, please explain a little more carefully your doubt.