# How to save the pipeline after deletion of Data Fusion instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, pipeline, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-data-fusion

Is it possible to keep the pipeline even after the Data Fusion instance is deleted? We are planning to delete the instance every day at EOD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export a pipeline from either the pipeline list view or  pipeline detail view and import it in pipeline studio when you need it.

[Pipeline List View Export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmHok.png)

[Pipeline Detail View Export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31ysv.png)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I have one more query regarding this, that is there any way to automate this Export/Import process?

Comment: Might this solve your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58839608/import-export-datafusion-pipelines

Comment: Hi Fernando, Thank you, it really helped. Thankyou!!